# How to resample time series with pandas and pad dates within a range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `Series` indexed by timestamp.  I group by the value in the series, so I end up having a number of groups each either their own timestamp indexed `Series`.  I then want to `resample()` the group series each to weekly, but want to **align the first date across all groups**.

My code looks something like this:

```
grp = df.groupby(df)
for userid, user_df in grp:
    resample = user_df.resample('1W', __some_fun)
```

The only way I have found to make sure alignment happens on the left hand side of the date is to fake pad each group with one value, e.g.:

```
grp = df.groupby(df)
for userid, user_df in grp:
    user_df = user_df.append(pandas.Series([0], index=[pandas.to_datetime('2013-09-02')]))
    resample = user_df.resample('1W', __some_fun)
```

It seems to me that this must be a common workflow, any pandas insight?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help here.  You have a Series but non-unique index?  Or do you mean DataFrame but just used Series loosely?  Don't anwer that btw, just post the data and desired output please.